# can not identify the cause of error to connect xampp (openfire) server by java

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am new in xmpp. For a whole day i and my project member stuck in connecting  xmpp server(openfire version 3.9.3) by java. I am using smack(version 4.0.7) library. Here is simple code...

```
        ConnectionConfiguration config =new ConnectionConfiguration("servername",5223);
        XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
            // Connect to the server
            try {
                    connection.connect();
                connection.login("username", "password");

                }  catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But when i run this code this errors is showing ...`

```
 org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.throwConnectionExceptionOrNoResponse(XMPPConnection.java:548)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.throwConnectionExceptionOrNoResponse(XMPPTCPConnection.java:867)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader.startup(PacketReader.java:113)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initConnection(XMPPTCPConnection.java:482)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:440)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:811)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:396)
at test.third.<init>(third.java:19)
at test.third.main(third.java:34)
```

There may be a silly mistake and easy solution, i googled but but somehow i am not getting the right solution.please help me. Thanks in advance